# creating a feedback form using php sessions

Tags: php, session

Iam trying to create a feedback form that has various ratings for a professor. Once the student makes their selection it should be displayed back to them.
This is to be done using sessions or cookies.
I have tried doing it with sessions but unable to create an array and then show the results.

Comment: what have you done so far. show us some efforts.

Comment: I have done for on question. I'm unable to create an array of sessions and radio buttons to show selection for each question....